# Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction in terms of Jacobi theta functions?

Tags: special-functions, modular-forms, continued-fractions, theta-functions

The Rogers-Ramanujan cfrac is,

$$r = r(\tau)= \cfrac{q^{1/5}}{1+\cfrac{q}{1+\cfrac{q^2}{1+\ddots}}}$$

If $q = \exp(2\pi i \tau)$, then it is known that,

$$\frac{1}{r}-r =\frac{\eta(\tau/5)}{\eta(5\tau)}+1\tag1$$

$$\frac{1}{r^5}-r^5 =\left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}\right)^6+11\tag2$$

with the *Dedekind eta function*, $\eta(\tau)$.

**Q:** Is there a similar simple identity known using ratios of the [*Jacobi theta functions*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_n(0,q)$?

---

$\color{brown}{Edit}$: In response to a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425004/rogers-ramanujan-continued-fraction-in-terms-of-theta-functions?noredirect=1#comment3048748_1425004), here are some details. Suppose we don't know $(2)$. One way to find such relations is to use known identities. Given the j-function $j(\tau)$, we have,

$$j(\tau)=-\frac{(r^{20} - 228r^{15} + 494r^{10} + 228r^5 + 1)^3}{r^5(r^{10} + 11r^5 - 1)^5}\tag3$$

$$j(\tau)=\frac{(5x^2+10x+1)^3}{x^5}\tag4$$

where $x = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\sqrt{5}\,\eta(5\tau)}\right)^6$. Equate $(3),\,(4)$,

$$-\frac{(r^{20} - 228r^{15} + 494r^{10} + 228r^5 + 1)^3}{r^5(r^{10} + 11r^5 - 1)^5} = \frac{(5x^2+10x+1)^3}{x^5}\tag5$$

and using symbolic software like *Mathematica* to factor $(5)$, we find one factor is given by,

$$\frac{1}{r^5}-r^5 =125x+11\tag6$$

and it only takes minor tweaking to make $(6)$ have the form of $(2)$. Thus, all we need is to express $j(\tau)$ not by an *eta quotient* $x$, but by a *theta quotient* $y=\left(\frac{\vartheta_n(0,q)}{\vartheta_n(0,q^5)}\right)^k$ so that,

$$j(\tau) = \frac{f_1(y)}{f_2(y)}\tag7$$

is a ratio of polynomials in $y$.

$\color{brown}{P.S.}$ The motivation for this is that the general quintic is solvable by the Rogers-Ramanujan cfrac via the eta quotient above as described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425349/).

Comment: The answer is in W.Duke's paper ***continued fractions and modular functions***,equation (4.9)

Comment: @Nicco: Thanks. By the way, can you ask a question on the forum how to solve the _Brioschi quintic_ using elliptic functions? (I have an answer that may be useful to you and others interested, and is the reason for this theta function post.)

Comment: @ Tito PiezasIII :I have asked the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425349/different-ways-of-solving-the-brioschi-quintic-in-terms-of-elliptic-functions)

Comment: @Nicco: Thanks. Right now, I can do so using the complete elliptic integral $K(k)$ and the Dedekind eta function, via $R(q)$. I'm trying to adapt the method to the Jacobi theta.

Comment: From another source, we have $$\frac{1}{r^5}-r^5 = \Big(\frac{ \vartheta_2(0,q)\,\vartheta_3(0,q)\, \vartheta_4(0,q)  }{\vartheta_2(0,q^5)\,\vartheta_3(0,q^5)\, \vartheta_4(0,q^5) }\Big)^2+11$$ but I find this is cheating a little bit.

Comment: @ Tito PiezasIII:it looks awesome,though

Comment: The derivative of the theta function $$\theta_1(0,q)$$ is known to satisfy the identity $$\theta_1(0,q)\prime=\theta_2(0,q)\,\theta_3(0,q)\,\theta_4(0,q)$$

Comment: @Nicco: Very interesting. This would then imply $\theta_1(0,q)' = 2\eta^3(\tau)$. Substituting this into the identity, one recovers $$\frac{1}{r^5}-r^5 = \Big(\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(5\tau)}\Big)^6+11$$

Comment: Another way to express $\eta$ in terms of Jacobi theta functions is eq. $(20)$ at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html). This is not a nullvalue however.

Comment: @ccorn: Or from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Relations_to_Dedekind_eta_function).

Comment: Using basic identities, one can deduce a family of formulae for the RRCF like
$$r(\tau) = \frac
{\vartheta_1\!\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\middle|\tau'\right)}
{\vartheta_1\!\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\middle|\tau'\right)}
= \frac
{\vartheta_2(0\mid \tau')\,\vartheta_3(0\mid\tau')\,\vartheta_4(0\mid\tau')}
{2\,\vartheta_2\!\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\middle|\tau'\right)
\vartheta_3\!\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\middle|\tau'\right)
\vartheta_4\!\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\middle|\tau'\right)}$$
where $\tau'=-(5\tau)^{-1}$.
Unfortunately, the question requires thetanulls exclusively. Sigh.

Comment: Could you concretize what you are asking for? The question is interesting, but currently it is not clear to me what a valid answer would be. It seems you might be satisfied with an algebraic equation for $r$ with coefficients in terms of thetanulls. You have already given some. I have inspected your Brioschi quintic post, but to adapt the method to thetanulls one can go directly via $\eta$, that is, the $2\eta^3$ as a product of thetanulls, as already mentioned. Do you expect something drastically simpler? Whatever reformulation we can come up with, it would at best be equivalent, I'm afraid.

Comment: @ccorn: I have clarified the question. If you know of a formula for the j-function in terms of a theta quotient in just ***one*** thetanull $\frac{\vartheta_n(0,q)}{\vartheta_n(0,q^5)}$, then that can lead me to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My gut feeling is that such a thing should exist. Thinking...

Comment: @ccorn: Thanks to your prodding, I found what I was looking for. :) Kindly see answer below.

Comment: I have asked a question which assumes $(6)$ and proves $(3),(4)$ based on it. I also provide an answer based on modular equations. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4000258/72031).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Motivated by ccorns's comment, I decided to re-visit this question. After some effort, I found what I was looking for. The Rogers-Ramanujan cfrac is,

$$r = r(\tau)= \cfrac{q^{1/5}}{1+\cfrac{q}{1+\cfrac{q^2}{1+\ddots}}}$$

where $q = \exp(2\pi i \tau)$. It turns out we have the ***nice*** relations,

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{r^5}-r^5 
&=\,u^3+11\\
&= \frac{v(v-5)^2}{(v-1)^2}+11
\end{aligned}$$

where the three roots of the cubic in $u$ are *eta quotients*,

$$u_n = \left(\frac{\eta(\tau')}{\eta(5\tau')}\right)^2$$

with $\tau'=\tau+n$, while the three roots of the cubic in $v$ are *theta quotients*,

$$v_n = \left(\frac{\vartheta_{n+2}(0,p)}{\vartheta_{n+2}(0,p^5)}\right)^2$$

for the ***nome*** $p = e^{\pi i \tau}$ and for $n=0,1,2$.

Comment: Nice indeed. If there were a 2nd volume of Whittaker & Watson, this one would make it to the legendary "Shew that..." exercises.

Answer (score 5):

Given the *[Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)* 
$$
\vartheta_4(u,q)=1+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^nq^{n^2}\cos(2nu)
$$ 
I. Define the *Rogers-Ramanujan* as 
$$
R(q)=\frac{q^{1/5}}{1+}\frac{q}{1+}\frac{q^2}{1+}\frac{q^3}{1+}\ldots\textrm{, }\;|q|<1
$$ 
then
$$
R(e^{-x})=e^{-x/5}\frac{\vartheta_4(3ix/4,\,e^{-5x/2})}{\vartheta_4(ix/4,\,e^{-5x/2})}\textrm{, }\;x>0
$$
II. Define the *Ramanujan-Gordon-Gollniz* as
$$
H(q)=\frac{q^{1/2}}{1+q+}\frac{q^2}{1+q^3+}\frac{q^4}{1+q^5+}\frac{q^6}{1+q^7+}\ldots\textrm{, }\;|q|<1
$$
then
$$
H(e^{-x})=e^{-x/2}\frac{\vartheta_4(3ix/2,\,e^{-4x})}{\vartheta_4(ix/2,\,e^{-4x})}\textrm{, }\;x>0
$$

Comment: +1 This is very nice. I tested it with _Mathematica_ and they equate. Do you know if the _cubic cfrac_ and the _octic cfrac_ can be similarly expressed in terms of theta quotients?

Comment: Can you look at this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/a/259342/12905) about $x^5+y^5 = 1$? There are some functions $a,b,c,d$ there and the ratio $a/b$ can be expressed by Jacobi theta functions. Can you check if we can do so for the ratio $d/b$ as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry about the octic cfrac. Yes it seems to be non trivial. In Berndt's book (see: B.C. Berndt. "Ramanujan Notebooks III". Springer Verlag, New York (1991), In chapter 19 Entry 1) one can find the expansion
$$
M(q)=\tfrac{1}{2}\,q^{1/8}\frac{\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{n^2/2+n/2}}{\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{n^2}}=\frac{q^{1/8}}{1+}\frac{q}{1+q+}\frac{q^2}{1+q^2+}\frac{q^3}{1+q^3+}\ldots
$$
Hence if $|q|<1$ and
$$
\vartheta_3(z,q):=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{n^2}e^{2niz}
$$
For $x>0$ we have
$$
M(e^{-x})=\tfrac{1}{2}\,e^{-x/8}\frac{\vartheta_3(ix/4,e^{-x/2})}{\vartheta_3(0,e^{-x})}
$$
Equivalently, let $q = e^{2\pi i z}$, then
$$M(q) = \tfrac{1}{2}\,q^{1/8} \frac{\vartheta_3\big(i\ln(q^{1/4}),q^{1/2}\big)}{\vartheta_3(0,q)}=\frac{\eta(z)\,\eta^2(4z)}{\eta^3(2z)}$$
where $\eta(z)$ is the *Dedekind eta function*.

Comment: I've added some info to connect it to the $\eta(z)$ function.

Answer (score 1):

For the cubic $V(q)$ cfrac is
$$
V(q):=\frac{q^{1/3}}{1+}\frac{q+q^2}{1+}\frac{q^2+q^4}{1+}\frac{q^3+q^6}{1+}\ldots\textrm{, }|q|<1
$$
and
$$
V(e^{-x})=e^{-x/3}\frac{\vartheta_4(ix/4,e^{-3x})}{\vartheta_4(0,e^{-3x})}\textrm{, }x>0
$$
See more formulas in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.2393v2.pdf

Comment: +1 Great! Now all that is missing is Ramanujan's octic cfrac

Comment: The octic cfrac of Ramanujan is just the "elementary" continued fraction of Euler and can be evaluated (with theta functions) in a very simply way.

Comment: Kindly include so this list will be complete.

Answer (score 1):

Set $T=\sqrt{1-8V(q)^3}$, $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}$, $r>0$, then
$$
k_r^2=\frac{(1-T)(3+T)^3}{(1+T)(3-T)^3}
$$
where $k_r$ is the *elliptic singular modulus*. (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1304v2.pdf)