# On discriminants and nature of an equation's roots?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, roots, discriminant

*Edited*: All equations in the post are assumed to have all ***real*** coefficients and are ***[minimal polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicNumberMinimalPolynomial.html)***.

While trying to ascertain if the [*Brioschi quintic*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425349/) $B(x)=x^5-10cx^3+45c^2x-c^2=0$ could ever have $3$ real roots, I was led to the question if one can use the *[discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Nature_of_the_roots)* $D$ to settle this.

For $B(x)$, it is given by $D = 5^5c^8(-1+1728c)^2$ and it seems for quintics, if $D>0$, then there are either $0$ or $4$ complex roots $C=a+bi$ with $b\neq0$. Hence the Brioschi (with real coefficients) can never have $3$ real roots.

For other degrees $n$, by observing the data in the *[Database of Number Fields](http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/home)*, I was able to come up with the table below. The second and third columns give the number of complex roots $C=a+bi$.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Degree}\;n&\text{If}\;D>0&\text{If}\;D<0\\
2&0&2\\
3&2&0\\
4&{0,4}&{2}\\
5&{0,4}&{2}\\
6&2,6&0,4\\
7&0,4&2,6\\
8&{0,4,8}&{2,6}\\
9&{0,4,8}&{2,6}\\
{10}&2,6,10&0,4,8\\
{11}&0,4,8&2,6,10\\
{12}&{0,4,8,12}&{2,6,10}\\
{13}&{0,4,8,12}&{2,6,10}\\
{14}&{0,4,8,12}&{2,6,10,14}\\
{15}&{0,4,8,12}&{2,6,10,14}\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**Questions:**

1. Is the table true?
2. How do we predict the second and third columns for much *higher* $n$? For example, for $n=163$, does the second column start as $0,4,8,12,\dots$ or $2,6,10,14,\dots$?

Comment: When $D<0$ and $n=5$ does the brown 2 refer to there being 2 complex roots? If so the remaining 3 would be real (but possibly not all distinct). [Maybe I'm missing something here...] I see you may be restricting to $D>0$ for some reason.

Comment: @coffeemath: Yes. That's what it means. Thus, _if the table is true_, if your quintic with real coefficients has $D<0$, then you can be sure it has only 2 complex roots (and 3 real roots).

Comment: um excuse me but why aren't $2,7,11$ colored in red ?

Comment: @mercio: It was merely an error made in haste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that there is a mistake in your table.

Brill's theorem states that the sign of the discriminant of an algebraic number field is $(-1)^{r_2}$ where $r_2$ is the number of complex places. When we have a power basis for our number field, the minimal polynomial of the generator will have $2r_2$ complex roots. Thus the column for $D>0$ should only contain integers divisible by $4$, and when $D<0$ we have a number of complex roots $\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

For a specific example, $$x^3-x^2-3x+1$$ [has three real roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20x%5E3-%20x%5E2-3*x%20%2B%201%3D0) and [a discriminant of 148](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant%20x%5E3-%20x%5E2-3*x%20%2B%201).

Comment: I stand corrected. I think I have inverted some of the entries.  <sheepish tone>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the table is correct. $f = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)$ has discriminant $1194393600 > 0$ and 0 complex roots.

It doesn't have a direct citation from a reputable source, but the Wikipedia page you linked says that in general for $D > 0$ there is an integer $0 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{4}$ such that there are $4 k$ complex roots, and for $D < 0$ there is an integer $0 \leq k' \leq \frac{n-2}{4}$ such that there are $4k' + 2$ complex roots, which doesn't mesh with your table.

Comment: I have now changed the post.

Comment: Okay, so take $f = x^6 - x^4 + 2 x^4 - x^2 + x - 1$, which you mentioned in another comment. It has 4 complex roots, I believe.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, it seems I have inverted some entries.