# The trigonometric solution to the solvable DeMoivre quintic?

Tags: trigonometry, special-functions, roots, radicals

Using the relations for the *Rogers-Ramanujan cfrac* described in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1425004/4781),

$$\frac{1}{r}-r = x$$

$$\frac{1}{r^5}-r^5 = y$$

and eliminating $r$ yields,

$$x^5+5x^3+5x = y$$

This is the case $a=1$ of the solvable *[DeMoivre quintic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Examples_of_solvable_quintics)*,

$$x^5+5ax^3+5a^2x+b = 0\tag1$$

In general, it has the solution,

$$x = \left(\tfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4a^5}}{2}\right)^{1/5}-a\left(\tfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2+4a^5}}{2}\right)^{-1/5}\tag2$$

When $a=-1$, it can also be solved as,

$$x = 2\cos\Bigg(\tfrac{\arccos\Big(\tfrac{-b}{2}\Big)}{5}\Bigg) = 2\cos\Bigg(\tfrac{2\arctan\Big(\tfrac{\sqrt{2+b}}{\sqrt{2-b}}\Big)}{5}\Bigg)\tag3$$

> **Q:** When $\color{red}{a=1}$, is there a neat trigonometric solution similar to $(3)$?

**P.S.** A google [search](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mRC4VeCCSX0J:www.forgottenbooks.com/readbook_text/The_Solution_of_Equations_1000078458/33%20&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ph) revealed that it is may indeed be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Tito for the nice question. Here is a solution in terms of *hyperbolic* sine, which may not be what you want.
$$
\sinh(5t) = 5 \sinh t+ 20 \sinh^3 t + 16 \sinh^5 t.
$$
With $x = 2\sinh t$ and $b = -2\sinh 5t$, we have
$$
x^5+ 5 x^3 + 5 x + b = 0\tag1,
$$
which is the $a = 1$ case. So the solution is
$$
x = 2\sinh t = 2\sinh\left( \frac{\sinh^{-1}\left(-\frac{b}{2}\right)}{5} \right)\tag2
$$

Comment: Thanks! It turns out the general quintic can then be solved in terms of the _hyperbolic functions_. See my addendum to your answer.

Comment: By the way, do you know the expressions for ***all*** five roots of $(1)$? (The value $(2)$ is just one of the roots.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. Sorry for the late response.  I was about to say adding $2\pi i n$ on the numerator, then I found that you have already done that. :-)

Answer (score 5):

(*This is an addendum to hbp's answer*.)

I'm glad I raised a bounty for this question because, thanks to [hbp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/131476/hbp), we can show that ***the general quintic can be solved in terms of trigonometric or hyperbolic functions, plus some special functions***.

The general quintic can be reduced to the one-parameter *Brioschi* form,

$$w^5-10cw^3+45c^2w-c^2=0\tag1$$

with the five solutions (see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1425435/4781)),

$$w_n=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-c\,(x^2+4)(x^2-2x-4)^2}{b-11}}\tag2$$

and for $n=0,1,2,3,4$,

$$x_n=-2\,i\sin\Bigg(\tfrac{i\log\Big(\tfrac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4}}{2}\Big)\,-\,2\pi\, n}{5} \Bigg)=2\sinh\Bigg(\tfrac{\sinh^{-1}\Big(\tfrac{b}{2}\Big)\,+\,2\pi\,i\, n}{5}\Bigg) \tag3$$

$$b=\frac{v(v-5)^2}{(v-1)^2}+11$$

$$v=\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(0,p)}{\vartheta_2(0,p^5)}\right)^2$$

$$p=e^{\pi i \tau}=\exp(\pi i \tau)$$

$$\tau = i\frac{K(k')}{K(k)}= i\,\frac{\text{EllipticK[1-m]}}{\text{EllipticK[m]}}\tag4$$

$$m =\tfrac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-4u}\right)\tag5$$

and $u$ is a root of the cubic,

$$\frac{256(1-u)^3}{u^2}=\frac{1728c-1}{c}$$

The solution also uses the [*Jacobi theta function*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_j(0,p)$ (where $j=3$ or $4$ will work as well), the [*complete elliptic integral of the first kind*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) $K(k)$ and *[elliptic parameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parameter.html)* $m=k^2$ (with $\tau$ also given in *Mathematica* syntax above).

*Note 1*: Since $(2)$ and $(5)$ uses square roots, then the proper sign has to be chosen.

*Note 2*: At first, I was missing a neat form for $(3)$ so, after hbp's answer, I'm glad I posted this question.

Comment: Wow, that's cool! Glad to offer some little help to a mighty mind :-)

Comment: You claim that a general quintic can be solved in terms of trigonometric/hyperbolic functions. But your further explanation includes theta function and eliptic integrals.

Comment: @Anixx: I didn't say _only_. trigonometric functions. For its argument, it uses other special functions. But it's not easy to find _any_ function in the first place that can solve the general quintic.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII If I may ask, what field of math do you work in? I am trying to figure out which field gives you such vast experience with algebraic equations and identities.