# How to solve in radicals this family of equations for any degree $k$?

Tags: galois-theory, roots, closed-form, radicals

**Part I.** Given any constant $a,b$, the equation in $x$,

$$\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4a}}{2}\right)^{k}+\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4a}}{2}\right)^{k}=b\tag1$$

is solvable in radicals for any degree $k$. The general solution is,

$$x = \frac{-a}{\beta^{1/k}}+\beta^{1/k},\quad\text{where}\;\beta = \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a^k}}{2}$$

For example, expanding at $k=5$, we get the DeMoivre quintic,

$$x^5+5ax^3+5a^2x=b$$

**Part II.** Given any constant $a,b$, the equation in $x$,

$$\frac{\big(x+\sqrt{b}\big)^k+\big(x-\sqrt{b}\big)^k}{2}+a\frac{\big(x+\sqrt{b}\big)^k-\big(x-\sqrt{b}\big)^k}{2\sqrt{b}}=0\tag2$$

is also solvable in radicals for any $k$. For example, for $k=5$, we get,

$$x^5+5ax^4+10bx^3+10abx^2+5b^2x+ab^2=0$$

> **Question:** *What is the general solution of $(2)$?*

Comment: I have a doubt now since my answer is rather trivial... Did you want the polynomial or did you hope an explicit solution $x=\cdots$ ? (I should probably erase my answer!)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: The polynomials are easy to get by expansion. I was hoping for the explicit solution $x$. But as I look at your answer, it seems you are on the right track.

Comment: In the mean time I had reverted $(2)$ in my solution. Now are there others?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: I think all $k$ roots can be found by using something similar [to this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1547827/4781). (P.S. Maybe you can delete everything after $(3)$? The solution $x$ is what I'm after.)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: I figured out the expression for _all_ $k$ roots. Do you want me to do the edit, or did you figure it out also?  :)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty and sorry for the delay but I prefer to check numerically my answers. Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite your equation $\,(2)\,$ for $\;r:=\dfrac {\sqrt{b}}x\,$ as :
$$\tag{1}\dfrac{(1+r)^k-(1-r)^k}{(1+r)^k+(1-r)^k}=-\frac {\sqrt{b}}a$$
then from [Ron Gordon's recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585604/21783) :
$$\tag{2}\tanh(k\;\operatorname{tanh^{-1}}r)=\frac{e^{(2 k \tanh^{-1} r)}-1}{e^{(2 k\tanh^{-1} r)}+1}=-\frac {\sqrt{b}}a$$

We may revert this to get one real solution :
$$\tag{3}\dfrac {\sqrt{b}}x=-\tanh\left(\frac 1k\tanh^{-1}\frac {\sqrt{b}}a\right)$$

Other solutions may be obtained by noticing that $\,e^{\large{(2 k \tanh^{-1} r+2\pi in)}}\,$ will give the same expansion in $(2)$ so that we have too :
 $$\tag{4}\tanh(k\;\operatorname{tanh^{-1}}r+\pi i n)=-\frac {\sqrt{b}}a$$
and the $k$ roots $x_n$ (for $n=0..k-1$) given by :
$$\tag{5}\boxed{\displaystyle x_n=-\frac 1{\sqrt{b}}\;\operatorname{cotanh}\left(\frac 1k\tanh^{-1}\frac {\sqrt{b}}a+\frac{\pi in}k\right)}$$
We may too revert the passage from $(1)$ to $(2)$ (with $k$ replaced by $\dfrac 1k$ and for $\alpha:=\dfrac {\sqrt{b}}a$ )
and rewrite $(5)$ as :
$$\tag{6}\frac {\sqrt{b}}x=-\dfrac{\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1/k}-1}{\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)^{1/k}+1}$$
that is :
$$\tag{7}x=\sqrt{b}\;\dfrac{1+R^{1/k}}{1-R^{1/k}}$$

where $\;R^{1/k}\;$ is one of the $k\;$ $k$-th roots of $\;R:=\dfrac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\dfrac{a+\sqrt{b}}{a-\sqrt{b}}$.

Comment: I'm glad you noticed that post with R. Gordon's answer.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: so am I. Excellent continuation!

Comment: One thing I would like though. This family has a solvable Galois group. Do you know a way to express your $x_n$ in terms of plain trigonometric functions? (Hence in radicals.)

Comment: I'll try to edit (and convert the log in powers if possible...)

Comment: Beautiful! The solution $(7)$ is just the analogous form I was hoping to find.

Comment: Glad you liked it @Tito. Now I'll have to verify it! :-)

Comment: Oh, I already tested it with _Mathematica_. Besides, the form is verification enough for me. If it had been ugly and complicated, I would be doubtful. But since it is beautiful and simple, then it has to be true. (Admittedly not the most rigorous test.)  :)

Comment: So true! Excellent and fruitful further Explorations. Cheers,