# Can we list explicitly all types of polynomial equations of one unknown that are solvable by radicals?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots, radicals

Deciding if a given polynomial equation is solvable in radicals is a complex algorithmic task.

**Can we instead list explicitly all types of polynomial equations of one unknown that are solvable by radicals?

Or all types of polynomial equations of one unknown that are not solvable by radicals?**

[Ritt 1922] collects all rational functions of prime degree with inverses expressible in terms of radicals. So the corresponding polynomial equations are contained.

We get i. a. the following polynomial equations from Ritt's paper.

$a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}$
$m\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$

1.)

$$a(z+b)^m+c=0$$

2.)

$T_m$: the m-th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind

$$aT_m(bz+c)+d=0$$

$$a\left(2^{m-1}(bz+c)^m+\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}(-1)^i\frac{m}{i}\prod_{l=0}^{i-2}(m-i-1-l)\cdot 2^{m-2i-1}(bz+c)^{m-2i}\right)+d=0$$

Ritt continues with rational functions that are related to [Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$](https://en.wikipedia.org%5Cwiki%5CWeierstrass_elliptic_function). **Can they be listed explicitly?**

**Are there other schemes/systems/methods to list the requested types of polynomial equations explicitly?**
$\ $

[[Ritt 1922] Ritt, J. F.: On algebraic functions which can be expressed in terms of radicals. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 24 (1922) (1) 21-30](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1922-024-01/S0002-9947-1922-1501211-X/)

Answer (score 6):

No, we cannot have a complete list of such families. But we do have the complete criterion: namely, that its Galois group is solvable. And the "[*Inverse Galois problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#A_simple_example:_cyclic_groups)" can help *explicitly* construct infinitely many solvable equations, such as the first family below.

---

**Family 1.**

Minimal polynomials of $x=2\cos(2\pi/p)$. The link above derives the first (for $p=7$),

$$x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$
$$x^5 + x^4 - 4x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x + 1 = 0$$
and so on for all $p$.

---

**Family 2.**

[Hilbert class polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html). Examples for degrees 1 and 2 are,

$$j\Big(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-163}}2\Big) = -640320^3$$
$$j\Big(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-235}}2\Big) = -528^3\big(8875+3969\sqrt5\big)^3$$

and so on for all degrees $n$. These typically have huge coefficients.

---

**Family 3.**

[Weber class polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_modular_function). These generate the same field as above but have smaller coefficients. Examples for degrees 5 and 7 are,

$$ 0 = -1 - 2x - 2x^2 - x^3 + x^5$$
$$ 0 = -1 - x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 - x^5 - 2x^6 + x^7$$

which uses $d=\frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}2$ and $d=\frac{1+\sqrt{-71}}2$. Etc.

---

**Family 4.**

This is 2-parameter and also has [a trigonometric solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1537069/4781).

$$\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4a}}{2}\right)^{k}+\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4a}}{2}\right)^{k}=b$$

Expanding for $k=5$, we get the *DeMoivre quintic*,

$$x^5+5ax^3+5a^2x=b$$

In radicals,

$$x = \frac{-a}{\beta_1^{1/k}}+\beta_1^{1/k},\quad\text{where}\;\beta_1 = \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a^k}}{2}$$

---

**Family 5.**

This is also 2-parameter and likewise has a trigonometric [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1581041/4781).

$$\frac{\big(x+\sqrt{b}\big)^k+\big(x-\sqrt{b}\big)^k}{2}+a\frac{\big(x+\sqrt{b}\big)^k-\big(x-\sqrt{b}\big)^k}{2\sqrt{b}}=0$$

For $k=5$, we get,

$$x^5+5ax^4+10bx^3+10abx^2+5b^2x+ab^2=0$$

recently discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4720550/4781). In radicals,

$$x=\sqrt{b}\;\dfrac{1+\beta_2^{1/k}}{1-\beta_2^{1/k}},\quad\text{where}\;\beta_2=\frac{a+\sqrt{b}}{a-\sqrt{b}}$$

---

(*Added later re comment.*)

**Family 6.**

This is a deg-$5$ [multi-parameter family](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1823217/4781). Given the depressed quintic,

$$x^5 + 10c x^3 + 10d x^2 + 5 e x + f = 0$$

If $c\neq 0$ and the coefficients form a "square",

$$\big(c^3 + d^2 - c e\big) \big(25 c^4 - 10 c^2 e + e^2 + 16 c d^2\big) = \big(c^2 d + d e - c f\big)^2$$

then the quintic **is solvable**. Its roots obey,

$$x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_4 + x_4 x_5 + x_5 x_1 - (x_1 x_3 + x_3 x_5 + x_5 x_2 + x_2 x_4 + x_4 x_1) = 0$$

Since the square condition is only a quadratic in $f$, it is quite easy to find polynomials in $c,d,e$ such that $f$ is rational. An example is the *Lehmer quintic*,

$$x^5 + n^2x^4 - (2n^3 + 6n^2 + 10n + 10)x^3 + (n^4 + 5n^3 + 11n^2 + 15n + 5)x^2 + (n^3 + 4n^2 + 10n + 10)x + 1 = 0$$

which, transformed to depressed form, obey the square relation above.

---

**Family 7.**

Analogous to the Lehmer quintic, this is the deg-$7$ *Hashimoto-Hoshi septic*,

$$\small 0 = x^7 - (a^3 + a^2 + 5a + 6)x^6 + 
  3(3a^3 + 3a^2 + 8a + 4)x^5 + (a^7 + a^6 + 9a^5 - 5a^4 - 15a^3 - 22a^2 - 36a - 8)x^4 - a(a^7 + 5a^6 + 12a^5 + 24a^4 - 6a^3 + 2a^2 - 20a - 16)x^3 + a^2(2a^6 + 7a^5 + 19a^4 + 14a^3 + 2a^2 + 8a - 8)x^2 - a^4(a^4 + 4a^3 + 8a^2 + 4)x + a^7$$

then there is a root ordering that obey,

$$
x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_4 + \dots + x_7 x_1 - (x_1 x_3 + x_3 x_5 + x_5 x_7 + \dots + x_6 x_1) = 0$$

One can extrapolate this root pattern and find higher families for prime $p=11,13,\dots$

---

**Family 8.**

This generalizes Family 4. That is essentially,

$$x_p = u_1^{1/p}+u_2^{1/p}$$

where $u_i$ are **quadratic** roots. Family 8 instead uses **cubic** roots $(a,b,c)$ of the special $u^3-nu^2+(n-3)u+1 = 0.$ Define,

$$x_7 = (a^3b)^{1/7}+(b^3c)^{1/7}+(c^3a)^{1/7}$$

with roots $a,b,c$ ordered correctly. Then $x_7$ is a root of,

$$x^7 - 14x^4 + 7n x^3 - 14(n - 3)x^2 - 28x + (n^2 + 5n + 9) = 0$$

Likewise,

$$x_{13} = (a^4b)^{1/13}+(b^4c)^{1/13}+(c^4a)^{1/13}$$
$$\; x_{19} = (a^5b^2)^{1/19}+(b^5c^2)^{1/19}+(c^5a^2)^{1/19}$$
$$x_{31} = (a^6b)^{1/31}+(b^6c)^{1/31}+(c^6a)^{1/31}\;$$
$$x_{37} = (a^7b^3)^{1/37}+(b^7c^3)^{1/37}+(c^7a^3)^{1/37}$$

are roots of parametric equations of degs $p=13, 19, 31, 37,$ and so on for prime $p=6m+1.$ See this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/438594/12905) for more details.

---

**Family 9.**

This generalizes Family 8. Predictably, it uses special **quintic** roots $x_i$,

$$z = F_1(x_i)^{1/11}+F_2(x_i)^{1/11}+F_3(x_i)^{1/11}+F_4(x_i)^{1/11}+F_5(x_i)^{1/11}$$

where $F_k(x_i)$ are functions of the roots $x_i$ and $z$ is a root of a parameteric equation of deg $p=11$. And so on for other prime $p=10m+1$. More details on this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/439116/12905).

Of course, **Family 10** would use deg-$7$ roots, **Family 11** would use deg-$11$ roots, *ad infinitum*.

---

**P.S.** There are *still* other families (such as those that use relations between two eta quotients) but this should suffice for now.

Comment: Also, for irreducible equations of prime degree $p$, a necessary (but not sufficient condition) that is solvable in radicals it is has either 1 real root or $p$ real roots, nothing in between. Thus, simply by looking at a graph of an irreducible quintic, if it has 3 real roots, automatically you know it is unsolvable in radicals.

Comment: "No, we cannot have a complete list of such families." That's a strong claim, do you have a citation/proof for it?

Comment: @NoahSchweber If we are to follow the OP’s two examples and focus on polynomial parameterizatiions, then there are infinitely many. Would you like to see the list extended a little more to include some uncommon ones?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've added two more families, for $p=5$ and $p=7$. The pattern for higher prime $p$ can be extrapolated from there.