# Closed-form solution to the transcendental equation

Tags: special-functions, transcendental-equations

Could you give me advice on how to find a closed-form solution $t>0$ to the following transcendental equation:

$$(t+1)^a - t^a = g$$

where $a>1$ and $g>1$. An accurate closed-form approximation for $t>0$ to see how $t$ depends on $a$ and $g$ could be also fine.
I guess the above equation defines for a fixed $a>1$ a special function of $g>1$ $$t=t_a(g).$$ Maybe, it is possible to make an appropriate substitution to express $t_a$ by other special functions.

Many Thanks!
Piotr

Comment: There isn't even a closed-form solution to $(t+1)^6-t^6=g$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, not in radicals.  Maybe with Bring radicals or hypergeometric functions?

Comment: @Gerry Yes, maybe in terms of hypergeometric functions. In general, no way with radicals. A special substitution is needed.

Comment: @Robert A power series solution w.r.t. $g$ would be also ok.

Comment: If one does find a solution, then for $a\in\Bbb N$, there are at most $a$ solutions.

Comment: @Tyma: Are you sure that in the second term is $1-x$ not $x-1$ ?

Comment: @Piotr The goal of the comment was to show a similar question, but the second term should be $(x-1)$. Another form is $\sec^{2a}(x)-\tan^{2a}(x)=g,t=\tan^2(x)$

Comment: Many Thanks, Tyma. I also thought about generalized trigonometric hyperbolic functions.

Comment: If $g$ is large, I think that very good approximations could be obtained using $t=\sinh^2(x)$ and solving $\log \left(\cosh ^{2 a}(x)-\sinh ^{2 a}(x)\right)=\log(g)$.

Comment: @Piotr Was this answer deleted: “I haven’t tried. My PHD student found some closed form solution for a certain range of alpha and …”? It appeared 20 minutes ago and now is invisible to me/others.

Comment: @Tyma That's strange. I did not delete my answer.

Comment: @Piotr What did it say?

Comment: @Tyma: please contact me by email. I have some nice results that can be published.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is an equation of [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). It's an irreducible algebraic equation in dependence of $(t+1)^a$ and $t^a$. Because the terms $(t+1)^a,t^a$ are algebraically independent, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $t$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).
I don't know when the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) for $a\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

For rational $a$, the equation is related to an algebraic equation over the reals, and we can use the known solution methods in radicals, Bring radicals etc.

see also:
[Can we list explicitly all types of polynomial equations of one unknown that are solvable by radicals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241977/can-we-list-explicitly-all-types-of-polynomial-equations-of-one-unknown-that-are)

For $|t|\le 1$, we can use $(t+1)^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{a}{n}t^n$ and apply Lagrange inversion.

Comment: @Tyma: Many Thanks! What do you think about generalized trigonometric hyperbolic functions that correspond to the functional equation $|y|^p−|x|^q=1$
, see the book of R. Mickens "Generalized trigonometric and hyperbolic functions", CRC Press 2019? I think the case $p=q=a$
 is allowed. What do you think about substitution $t/g^{1/a}=\sinh_{a,a}(z)$
 and $(t+1)/g^{1/a}=\cosh_{a,a}(z)$
 ?

Comment: We would arrive at $\cosh_{a,a}(z)-\sinh_{a,a}{(z)}=g^{-1/a}$.

Comment: @Piotr I am not sure since there is a but of confusion. All I did was substitute the tangent function, but squared: $t=(\tan(x))^2$ to get $(\sec(x))^{2a}-(\tan(x))^{2a}=g$. The [tangent function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tangent.html) is not a generalized hyperbolic function. Also, there probably no free copy of the book. However, [this article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHyperbolicFunctions.html) has more information on $1757$ Riccati’s version of these functions

Comment: @Tyma: At the special point 'x' being the solution to this transcendental eq. they might be represented as generalized hyperbolic functions. Theses functions are still not well investigated.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it could be possible to have decent *approximations* letting $t=\sinh^2(x)$ and then to look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log \left(\cosh ^{2 a}(x)-\sinh ^{2 a}(x)\right)-k \qquad \text{with} \quad k=\log(g)$$
Around $x=0$
$$f(x)+k=a x^2 + O(x^4)$$

With $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{k}{a}}$, the first iterate of Newton method should probably be good.

Trying

- $a=e$ and $k=\pi$ give $x_0=0.9302$, $x_1=1.3158$ while the solution is $x=1.3125$
- $a=\pi$ and $k=e$ give $x_0=1.0751$, $x_1=1.0494$ while the solution is $x=1.0475$

Answer (score 0):

$\def\B{\operatorname B}\def\P{\operatorname P}$
**Fourier Series:**
Maybe someone who knows [Mellin transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) better can find a shorter solution than with a [Fourier sine series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier+sine+series) solution:

$$(t+1)^a-t^a=g\implies t_a(g)=\frac2{2^a-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{\pi n g}{2^a-1}\right)\int_0^1 at((t+1)^{a-1}-t^{a-1})\sin\left(\frac{\pi n((t+1)^a-t^a)}{2^a-1}\right)dt;1\le g<2^a-1$$

[graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%7Bx%2C2%2F%282%5Ee-1%29+sum%5Bsin%28pi+n+%28%28x%2B1%29%5Ee-x%5Ee%29%2F%282%5Ee-1%29%29+Nintegrate%5Be+t+%28-t%5E%28-1+%2B+e%29+%2B+%281+%2B+t%29%5E%28-1+%2B+e%29%29+sin%28%28n+%CF%80+%28-t%5Ee+%2B+%281+%2B+t%29%5Ee%29%29%2F%28-1+%2B+2%5Ee%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%221%22) of $t_e((t+1)^e-t^e)=t$ to $100$ terms:

[image]

$t_e(x)$ plot:

[image]

Sine Taylor series:

$$\int_0^1 at((t+1)^{a-1}-t^{a-1})\sin\left(\frac{\pi n((t+1)^a-t^a)}{2^a-1}\right)dt= a\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}\left(\frac{\pi n}{2^a-1}\right)^{2m+1}\int_0^1 t((t+1)^{a-1}-t^{a-1})((t+1)^a-t^a)^{2m+1}dt$$

binomial theorem:
$$a\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)!}\left(\frac{\pi n}{2^a-1}\right)^{2m+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}k(-1)^k \int_0^1 t((t+1)^{a-1}-t^{a-1})(t+1)^{a(2m-k+1)} t^{ak}dt$$
Finally, use the [incomplete beta $\B_x(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28x%2Ca%2Cb%29) function:
$$\int_0^1 t((t+1)^{a-1}-t^{a-1})(t+1)^{a(2m-k+1)} t^{ak}dt=(-1)^{-ak}\B_{-1}(ak+2,a(2m-k+2))+(-1)^{-a(k+1)}\B_{-1}(a(k+1)+1,a(2m-k+1)+1)$$

When $n=3$, the series coefficient [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+Nintegrate%5Bt+%28-t%5E%28-1+%2B+e%29+%2B+%281+%2B+t%29%5E%28-1+%2B+e%29%29+sin%28%283+%CF%80+%28-t%5Ee+%2B+%281+%2B+t%29%5Ee%29%29%2F%28-1+%2B+2%5Ee%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) [equals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5E%28m%2Bk%29%2F%28%282m-k%2B1%29%21+k%21%29+%283+pi%2F%282%5Ee-1%29%29%5E%282m%2B1%29+%28+%28-1%29%5E%28-e+k%29Beta%28-1%2Ce+k%2B2%2Ce%282m-k%2B2%29%29%2B%28-1%29%5E%28-e%28k%2B1%29%29+Beta%28-1%2Ce%28k%2B1%29%2B1%2Ce+%282m-k%2B1%29%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C2%E2%80%A225%2B1%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C25%7D%5D) our series expansion of it. You can show the same for any other $n$ series coefficient. Therefore:
$$\boxed{(t+1)^a-t^a=g\implies t=t_a(g)=\frac{2a}{2^a-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}\frac{(-1)^{m+k}}{(2m-k+1)!k!}\left(\frac{\pi n}{2^a-1}\right)^{2m+1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi n g}{2^a-1}\right)\left((-1)^{-ak}\B_{-1}(ak+1,a(2m-k+2))+(-1)^{-a(k+1)}\B_{-1}(a(k+1)+1,a(2m-k+1)+1)\right),1\le g<2^a-1}$$

If $k$’s upper bound is infinity, then possibly all three sums are interchangeable. Also, Fourier series is slow, but does eventually converge to the wanted value, as shown by the graphs. Expanding the incomplete beta function a sum and switching sums may give another series solution.

**Legendre Fourier Series:** Using [Legendre $\P_v(x)$ polynomial transforms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transform_(integral_transform)):

$$t_a(g)=\frac a{2^a-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (4n+3) \P_{2n+1}\left(\frac g{2^a-1}\right)\int_0^1 \P_{2n+1}\left(\frac{(t+1)^a-t^a}{2^a-1}\right) t ((t+1)^{a-1}-t^{a-1})dt,1\le g<2^a-1$$

Integrating from $-1$ to $0$ likely will not simplify the integral as much. Composing $t_e(x)$ with the inverse [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%7Bx%2Csum%5BlegendreP%282+n%2B1%2C%28%28x%2B1%29%5Ee-x%5Ee%29%2F%282%5Ee-1%29%29%284n%2B3%29+Nintegrate%5B%28%28-t%5EE+%2B+t+%281+%2B+t%29%5E%28-1+%2B+E%29%29+E+LegendreP%5B1+%2B+2+n%2C+%28-t%5EE+%2B+%281+%2B+t%29%5EE%29%2F%28-1+%2B+2%5EE%29%5D%29%2F%28-1+%2B+2%5EE%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C6%7D%5D%7D%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%221%22)  the identity:

[image]

$t_e(x)$:

[image]

Expanding $\P_{2n+1}(y)$ as a series and then as a binomial series will again give incomplete beta functions from the remaining integral. There should be a simpler solution than an infinite series and 2 finite series maybe through [complex integrals](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.526448) or with [Teixeira’s theorem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Teixeira%E2%80%99s+theorem&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22MathWorld%22%2C+%22TeixeirasTheorem%22%7D) etc, but I have little experience with contour integrals.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution! Many Thanks! Did you try Legendre polynomials instead of a sine basis? I think there is no particular restriction for the upper bound of $g$ if one modifies the series. It could be for example $1\le g \le 3^a-1$.

Comment: One more observation: I expect that the function $t_a(g)$ is analytic for $g\ge 1$, and of such form $t_a(g) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty c_k (1-1/g)^k$ since $g=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (1-1/g)^k$ for $g\ge 1$. Am I right or there are singularities of the higher-order derivatives?

Comment: @Piotr A problem with expanding the period of the Fourier series is that it converges more slowly in general. The Legendre fourier series would make  something of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(n+\frac12\right)\sum_{m=0}^{k} c_{n,k}\int_a^b t((t+1)^{a-1}-t^{a-1})((t+1)^a-t^a)^m dt$$ simplifying the sums a bit; this idea will be attempted soon. If you mean [Lagrange inversion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lagrange+inversion+theorem), like a Taylor series, for $t_a(g)$, then every attempt for it I did diverged.

Comment: To apply Legendre polynomials, one must know $t_a(1)$ or transform $(t+1)^a-t^a$ so that solving for $t$ when the transformed equation equals $\pm 1$: $\int_{-1}^1 P_m(x) t_a(x)dx=\int_{t_a(-1)}^{t_a(1)}(\dots)dx$

Comment: I would work with Legedre polynomials in transformed variables, e.g., on [0, 2^a-1] first. Then, after substituting, you will get integrals on [1,2]. Chebyshev polynomials with weights 1/sqrt{1-x^2} are better regarding convergence but there will be a problem with the transformed interval for integration - I guess.  Also, Jacobi functions are ok for Fourier expansion. They are used for solving problems with Truly Nonlinear Oscillators.

Comment: Maybe, we could invent our own Fourier basis for this particular problem. Please contact me: piotr_math@arcor.de. I will send you useful materials, and we can arrange more plans (including a common publication). There is deep math behind this equation.

Comment: @Piotr It is ok; I post work as answers here. You can try asking on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) with your own progress so far. Jacobi functions have a weight like $(t+1)^c t^d$, but will not make a simpler integrand. Let me try a generalized Fourier series one more time.

Comment: There is a simplification with tabular integration to get coefficients as something like $\int \cos(t^a+(t-1)^a+c)dt$ or $\int P_n(t^a+(t-1)^a+c)dt $

Comment: @Piotr Does using orthogonal polynomials over sine, cosine make finding the generalized fourier series coefficients easier for an inverse function?