# How can we solve the particular equation $16x^5-200x^3-200x^2+25x+30=0$ in closed form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, galois-theory, radicals

> How can we solve the following quintic in closed form ?
> $$16x^5-200x^3-200x^2+25x+30=0$$

What is special about this equation?  What can we say about solvability?  I'm not particularly into math.  I saw this equation in a discussion group.  Here are some ideas about the equation from non-mathematicians .

1. There is no closed-form formula for $5$-degree equations. Therefore there is no solution.  In my opinion this is wrong.  For example, $x^5=1$ can be easily solved.  The true version if that idea would be there is no general solution formula . (by radicals)
2. The equation is not factored.  Therefore, there is no closed-form solution.  This idea is also wrong in my opinion.  Because the factors do not have to be rational numbers.
3. Wolfram Alpha does not give closed form for the equation.  Therefore, it cannot be solved.  I cannot comment on this idea.

I found that the quintic is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

I've heard a little bit about Galois theory.  But I don't have the mathematical knowledge.  If possible, could you help to find out if this equation is solvable?  The problem author argues that the equation has a solution.

I tried WA software several times. But, it does not succeed.

Comment: "There is no solution formula for 5-degree equations. Therefore there is no solution." Who said that?

Comment: @stange I wrote ideas from discussion group .

Comment: This equation has 5 solutions; whether we can express them in closed form is the question.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+16x%5E5-200x%5E3-200x%5E2%2B25x%2B30%3D0) has no problem with this.

Comment: @lulu Approximate solutions ?

Comment: Of course.  As you pointed out, these aren't conveniently expressible as radicals.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. We are interested in closed-form formula.

Comment: And how do you want those expressed?  You already mentioned that you are aware that there is no solution in radicals to the general quintic.  Is there any reason to imagine that this quintic is somehow special?

Comment: @lulu Yes. The author said, she has a closed form formula .

Comment: According to Magma, this polynomial has Galois group $F_5$, the Frobenius group of order 20. Since this group is solvable (see [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/GaloisGroup/5T3), for instance), then polynomial is solvable by radicals. Magma has a `SolveByRadicals` command, which you can try on their [online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). The output is too large for me to put here.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn  Good find.  What's the syntax they want?  Could you post it below as a solution?  I'd like to use that calculator.

Comment: But, why the downvote ?

Comment: Well, it's certainly irreducible <- 5-Eisenstein.

Comment: In Wolfram Mathematica roots in radilcs can get from `Factor[30 + 25 x - 200 x^2 - 200 x^3 + 16 x^5, Extension -> Cos[ArcCos[-1/Sqrt[5]]/5]]`

Comment: This [link](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/?input=R%3Cx%3E:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());%0Df:=16*x%5E5-200*x%5E3-200*x%5E2%2B25*x%2B30;%0DG,data:=GaloisGroup(f);%0DTransitiveGroupDescription(G);%0DIsSolvable(G);%0DK,roots:=SolveByRadicals(f:Name:=%22K.%22);%0DK:Maximal;%0D%5BK!r:r%20in%20roots%5D;) contains *Magma* program to get the solutions of the OP equation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This polynomial $f$ has Galois group $F_5$, the [Frobenius group of order 20](https://www.lmfdb.org/GaloisGroup/5T3). Since this group is solvable, then $f$ is solvable by radicals. Here are *Magma* commands showing this.

```
R<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
f := 16*x^5-200*x^3-200*x^2+25*x+30;
G, data := GaloisGroup(f);
TransitiveGroupDescription(G);
IsSolvable(G);
```

which give as output

```
F(5) = 5:4
true
```

The docstring for the command `SolveByRadicals` describes how it gives solutions to a solvable polynomial:

> Compute a splitting field as a radical tower and the roots of $f$ as elements in this tower. Return also the non-trivial roots of unity used.

(See [here](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/424#4476) for more details.) We enter

```
K, roots := SolveByRadicals(f : Name := "K.");
K:Maximal;
```

which yields output

```
   K<K.1>
     |
     |
  $1<K.2>
     |
     |
  $2<K.3>
     |
     |
  $3<K.4>
     |
     |
     Q

K  : K.1^5 + 1/512*(-1875*K.4 - 3125)*K.3*K.2 - 2560000000
$1 : K.2^2 + 15118284881920000*K.4 - 34359738368000000
$2 : K.3^2 + 32*K.4 + 160
$3 : K.4^2 - 5
```

Denote by $\alpha_i$ the elements `K.i` for $i = 1, \ldots, 4$. Then this output is saying that we have a chain of simple radical extensions
$$
K = K_1 \supseteq K_2 \supseteq K_3 \supseteq K_4 \supseteq \mathbb{Q}
$$
where $K_i = K_{i+1}(\alpha_i)$ and the $\alpha_i$ satisfy the equations
\begin{align*}
0&={\alpha_1}^5+1/512(-1875\alpha_4-3125)\alpha_3\alpha_2-2560000000\\
0&={\alpha_2}^2+15118284881920000\alpha_4-34359738368000000\\
0&={\alpha_3}^2+32\alpha_4+160\\
0&={\alpha_4}^2-5\,.\end{align*}
Or in other words,
\begin{align*}
\alpha_4 &= \sqrt{5}\\
\alpha_3 &= \sqrt{-32 \alpha_4 - 160}\\
\alpha_2 &= \sqrt{-15118284881920000 \alpha_4 + 34359738368000000}\\
\alpha_1 &= \sqrt[5]{1/512 (1875 \alpha_4 + 3125) \alpha_3 \alpha_2 + 2560000000}
\end{align*}
up to choosing the correct roots of unity when taking these roots.

To express the roots of $f$ in terms of these generators, we enter `[K!r : r in roots];`, which yields

```
[
(1/268435456000000000*(-3*K.4 - 5)*K.3*K.2 + 1/128000000)*K.1^4 + 1/640000*K.1^3 + (1/33554432000000*(-3*K.4 - 5)*K.3*K.2 + 1/16000)*K.1^2 + 1/80*K.1,
((1/268435456000000000*(2*K.4 + 5)*K.3 + 1/13421772800000000*(K.4 + 3))*K.2 + (1/4096000000*(K.4 - 1)*K.3 + 1/512000000*(-K.4 - 1)))*K.1^4 + (-1/10240000*K.3 + 1/2560000*(K.4 - 1))*K.1^3 + ((1/67108864000000*(-K.4 - 5)*K.3 + 1/838860800000*(K.4 + 2))*K.2 + (1/256000*K.3 + 1/64000*(K.4 - 1)))*K.1^2 + (1/2560*(-K.4 + 1)*K.3 + 1/320*(-K.4 - 1))*K.1,
((1/536870912000000000*(-K.4 - 5)*K.3 + 1/6710886400000000*(K.4 + 2))*K.2 + (1/2048000000*K.3 + 1/512000000*(K.4 - 1)))*K.1^4 + (1/20480000*(K.4 - 1)*K.3 + 1/2560000*(-K.4 - 1))*K.1^3 + ((1/33554432000000*(2*K.4 + 5)*K.3 + 1/1677721600000*(-K.4 - 3))*K.2 + (1/512000*(-K.4 + 1)*K.3 + 1/64000*(-K.4 - 1)))*K.1^2 + (-1/1280*K.3 + 1/320*(K.4 - 1))*K.1,
((1/268435456000000000*(2*K.4 + 5)*K.3 + 1/13421772800000000*(-K.4 - 3))*K.2 + (1/4096000000*(-K.4 + 1)*K.3 + 1/512000000*(-K.4 - 1)))*K.1^4 + (1/10240000*K.3 + 1/2560000*(K.4 - 1))*K.1^3 + ((1/67108864000000*(-K.4 - 5)*K.3 + 1/838860800000*(-K.4 - 2))*K.2 + (-1/256000*K.3 + 1/64000*(K.4 - 1)))*K.1^2 + (1/2560*(K.4 - 1)*K.3 + 1/320*(-K.4 - 1))*K.1,
((1/536870912000000000*(-K.4 - 5)*K.3 + 1/6710886400000000*(-K.4 - 2))*K.2 + (-1/2048000000*K.3 + 1/512000000*(K.4 - 1)))*K.1^4 + (1/20480000*(-K.4 + 1)*K.3 + 1/2560000*(-K.4 - 1))*K.1^3 + ((1/33554432000000*(2*K.4 + 5)*K.3 + 1/1677721600000*(K.4 + 3))*K.2 + (1/512000*(K.4 - 1)*K.3 + 1/64000*(-K.4 - 1)))*K.1^2 + (1/1280*K.3 + 1/320*(K.4 - 1))*K.1
]
```

You can try this code for yourself using the [*Magma* online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/?input=R%3Cx%3E:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());%0Df:=16*x%5E5-200*x%5E3-200*x%5E2%2B25*x%2B30;%0DG,data:=GaloisGroup(f);%0DTransitiveGroupDescription(G);%0DIsSolvable(G);%0DK,roots:=SolveByRadicals(f:Name:=%22K.%22);%0DK:Maximal;%0D%5BK!r:r%20in%20roots%5D;).

Comment: Thanks, the solution is not readable, can you share us exact solution ?

Comment: Viktor, what are $K.4, K.3, K.2, K.1$ ? Could you write explicitly their values?

Comment: One minor question, was $F_{20}$ mistyped as $F_5$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Is this a step by step solution?

Comment: @user1174831 It looks like one to me. Ask the original answerer.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Original answerer doesn't answer comments.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I think there are differing conventions on how this group is denoted, similar to $D_n$ vs. $D_{2n}$ for dihedral groups. $F_5$ is the notation used both in the LMFDB link I gave and on its [GroupNames page](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/F5.html). $F_5$ is probably used because it's a subgroup of $S_5$, or maybe because it's isomorphic to the group of affine transformations on $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Comment: @Angelo The elements `K.i` are defined by the equations given below the field diagram. I'll add some further clarification.

Comment: How did  you find the Galois group?

Comment: @DavidLui I computed it using Magma, as in the post.

Comment: Why do you ignore my comment, can I ask ?

Comment: This [link](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/?input=R%3Cx%3E:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());%0Df:=16*x%5E5-200*x%5E3-200*x%5E2%2B25*x%2B30;%0DG,data:=GaloisGroup(f);%0DTransitiveGroupDescription(G);%0DIsSolvable(G);%0DK,roots:=SolveByRadicals(f:Name:=%22K.%22);%0DK:Maximal;%0D%5BK!r:r%20in%20roots%5D;) contains *Magma* program to get the solutions of the OP equation.

Comment: @user1174831 What is your question? I thought my edit would have addressed confusion over the meaning of the expressions for the roots.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn, could let me fix a part of your answer in fact it does appear as follows ? Moreover, could I change the final link in order to contain the program which solves the OP equation ? **begin{align*} 0 &= {\alpha_1}^5 + 1/512 (-1875 \alpha_4 - 3125) \alpha_3 \alpha_2 - 2560000000\\ 0 &= {\alpha_2}^2 + 15118284881920000 \alpha_4 - 34359738368000000\\ 0 &= {\alpha_3}^2 + 32 \alpha_4 + 160\\ 0 &= {\alpha_4}^2 - 5\, . \end{align*}**

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea how to solve the equation by radicals. However, I wanted to write it assuming that this answer will somehow work for us as well .

---

$$
\begin{align}16x^5-200x^3-200x^2&+25x+30=0\end{align}
$$

Using the linear substitution $\thinspace x:=u-\dfrac 12\thinspace $, we have :

$$
\begin{align}2u^5-5u^4-20u^3+10u^2&+10u-1=0\end{align}
$$

Then, recall the following trigonometric angle formula :

$$
\begin{align}\tan (5\alpha)&=\frac{\tan^5\alpha-10\tan^3\alpha+5\tan \alpha}{5\tan^4\alpha-10\tan^2\alpha+1}\end{align}
$$

Let $\thinspace\tan\alpha=u\thinspace$ and $\thinspace\tan (5\alpha)=a\thinspace$, then :

$$
\begin{align}u^5-5ay^4-10u^3+10au^2&+5u-a=0\end{align}
$$

which is equivalent to :

$$
\begin{align}2u^5-10au^4-20u^3+20au^2&+10u-2a=0\end{align}
$$

Therefore, taking $\thinspace a=\dfrac 12\thinspace $ then reduces the original equation to :

$$
\begin{align}&\tan (5\alpha)=\frac 12\\
\implies &\alpha=\frac 15\left(\arctan \left(\frac 12\right)+\pi k\right)\end{align}
$$

---

Thus, the final answer becomes :

$$
\begin{align}\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x=-\frac 12+\tan\left(\frac 15\left(\arctan \left(\frac 12\right)+\pi k\right)\right)}\end{align}
$$

where $\thinspace k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}\thinspace .$

Comment: I would appreciate insight into how you decided which trig function to recall in this situation! It seems a bit miraculous without further context.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Spend enough time with equations, one becomes familiar with some forms. For ex, the *DeMoivre quintic* is easy to recognize, $$x^5+5ax^3+5a^2x+b=0$$ But the *tangent quintic* is harder to spot, $$x^5 + 5a x^4 + 10 b x^3 + 10a b x^2 + 5b^2 x + a b^2=0$$ By the OP's inspired change of variables to get, $$2u^5-5u^4-20u^3+10u^2+10u-1=0$$ which we divide by 2, $$u^5-\tfrac52 u^4-10u^3+5u^2+5u-\tfrac12=0$$
one can now recognize the tangent quintic with $a=-\frac12$ and $b=-1$. Of course, what changes to do in the first place, there's where inspiration and ingenuity comes in.

Comment: In effect the trigonometric solution _is_ a radical solution; the forms are interconverted using the relationships between trig functions and complex exponentials. The given solution for $x$ may thus be rendered as $(-1/2)+[(1/i)(a-1)/(a+1)]$ where $a$ runs through all fifth roots of $(2+i)/(2-i)=(3+4i)/5$. Since all roots are real the radical form must involve complex radicands.

Answer (score 4):

If we are content to evaluate the solvability, we can use the Cayley resolvent described by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function). This gives an unexpected result.

First we note that the given equation has a leading coefficient of $2^4$. If we multiply by $2$ and define $y=2x$, we get an equation with smaller integer coefficients:

$ y^5-50y^3-100y^2+25y+60=0$

The Cayley resolvent method is applied to this equation. The quintic is solvable if the combination

$[P_3(z)]^2-1024z\Delta$

has a rational zero, where $\Delta$ and the coefficients of the cubic polynomial are evaluated from the coefficients of the reduced quintic. Formulas are given in the referenced Wikipedia article.

For the case at hand, the relevant outcome is that $P_3$ happens to have a zero constant term:

$P_3(z)=z^3-3000z^2+12800000z+\color{blue}{0}.$

This forces the complete sextic to also have a zero constant term, and so the sought rational root of the Cayley resolvent is simply zero!

Thus this particular quintic is solvable. But actually obtaining the solution requires a complex formula which, as reported by Wikipedia, runs to three pages (with the Cayley resolvent root already in hand). We might be content just to use the Magma online calculator from here on out, as Viktor Vaughn does, or use the trigonometric trick by lone student.

Comment: Given the quintic, $$x^5 + 10c x^3 + 10d x^2 + 5 e x + f = 0$$ then Watson's resolvent sextic has a zero constant term if the quintic's coefficients form a "square", $$\big(c^3 + d^2 - c e\big) \big(25 c^4 - 10 c^2 e + e^2 + 16 c d^2\big) = \big(c^2 d + d e - c f\big)^2$$ I tested it on your quintic in $y$ and it obeys the relation as well, so Cayley's and Watson's resolvents must be related. (Note: I just got a ping on [an old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1823217/4781) asking about resolvents with a zero root. Must be due to this new question.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I found that, the trigo formula worked .

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, I upvoted your answer. Very elegant and concise solution.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII  Ahh, many thank you, I just wanted to ping you . Thank you very much .

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII "*ping ... must be due to this new question*" $\;-\;$ Right, and thanks again for the followup there. The example in my comment was this quintic, just with $x \mapsto x/2$ to make it a simpler monic. The two quadratics you mention happen to have integer coefficients in this case, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII the two resolvents may be related. If we apply root squaring to the Watson form, as described in my answer to the pinged question, it looks like the Cayley form.