# Find all real solutions of the equation: $x^5+5x^3+5x+2017=0$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, quintics

I joined the math contest $1$ week ago ( In Azerbaijan).
There were $6$ questions. Unfortunately, I could solve $1$ question correctly.I know I can not write all the questions here, because It is against the MSE rules.I want to solve the $6th$ question that is known as the most difficult question.In fact, this question could not be solved by our teacher.

**Question $6$.  Find all real solutions of the equation:**

> $$x^5+5x^3+5x+2017=0$$

The only thing I have learned is that there are no integer solutions of this equation.Maybe, I'm wrong.

Comment: There are, in fact, no rational solutions. We can see this because the polynomial is monic, which means that any rational solution must be an integer which divides the constant term. $2017$ is prime, and therefore there are only four candidates to check: $\pm 1, \pm2017$. None of them are roots.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  I am in a state of exhaustion right now. I feel incompetent myself. Teacher, 1 question confirms that I solved the problem correctly.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think OP means to say, *"Unfortunately, I could solve only one question correctly."*

Comment: I 'm sorry English is my second language.

Comment: I'm sorry, too. English is also my second language. I have erased the comment.

Comment: This is the beauy of science ! For most of us, English is not our first language and we are able to communicate almost perfectly. Cheers to everybody.

Comment: @DietrichBurde While that makes $-1$ a root, it seems to me that the other roots aren't as nice. But I don't know.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. Beside $x=-1$, the roots are monstrous. Where did you find the test ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for those excellent words.

Comment: The test asked for integral roots only. I just could imagine, that there is a typo in the given polynmial, but I don't know.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Equation is correct ..because I work 10 days with equation..:) I believe we will find solution.

Comment: Dear friends, Equation is correct... I joined the Olympiad myself..

Comment: Dear mathematicians, I think we should find only real root here. Clearly, the complex root does not pass the definition of the problem.

Comment: It's a solveable quintic, see eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537069/the-trigonometric-solution-to-the-solvable-demoivre-quintic

Comment: Thank you everyone!! @leonbloy I understood

Answer (score 9):

Hint:

> Let $x=y-\frac 1y$
>
> We get $$y^5-\frac {1}{y^5}+2017=0$$
>
> And let $y^5=t$
>
> We get
>
> $$t^2+2017t-1=0$$

Comment: So simple .... when we know the elegant solution ! $\to +1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you so much :) Mathematics is  mother tongue all of us.As you say. :)

Comment: What I am almost sure is that my English is terrible but all of us communicate. In 1978, I was giving lectures in Russia; I was speaking French and all of that was translated (it was forbidden to not go through the translators). I don't know how my blabla was translated. But during coffes breaks, the Russian guys and I were doing Q/A just with equations; no problem .... except that the translators were very, very unhappy since unable to pick anything. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x) = x^5+5x^3+5x+2017$$

then $f'(x)= 5x^4+15x^2+5>0\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ (Strictly increasing function.)

and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)\rightarrow -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)\rightarrow \infty$ and $f(0) = 2017$

so $f'(x) = 0$ has no real roots and $f(x) = 0$ has exactly one real roots

Comment: ... and can you find this root?

Comment: No Arthur if you have any idea plz explain here thanks

Comment: I don't know what to do it either. I'm just a bit tired at the moment and apparently cranky. Sorry about the comment that was here before.

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari In the definition of the problem we must to find a real root.

Comment: Must we? I suppose *you* want to find it. Numerically, $x=- 4.36249608702$ is the real root.

Comment: It must be exact form (Teacher said).